# Images not showing up regardless of path

Tags: html, image, path, relative-path, src

I just launched a very simple site with 5 images.  4 of the images do not show up regardless of the path in the img tag.  The 5th image always shows up regardless of the path in the img tag.

I have tried "images/imagename.jpg", "/images.imagename.jpg", "../images.imagename.jpg".
I have tried putting images in root and using src="imagename.jpg".

The images that don't show up have this warning in the console:
[image]

Here is the current code:
http://avalynncirce.com/perduco

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img {max-height: 100vh;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="width:20%; float:left; position: fixed;">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#sv1">Workflow v1 Scatterplot</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mv1">Workflow v1 Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sv2">Workflow v2 Scatterplot</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mt">Collaboration Tool: Sketch (MAC and Online)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mt2">Collaboration Tool Tool: Figma (Windows)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div style="width:75%; float:right;">
            <section id="sv1">
                <hr style="margin: 50px;">
                <img src="/images/scatterplotv1.png">
            </section>

            <section id="mv1">
                <hr style="margin: 50px;">
                <img src="../images/menuv1.png">
            </section>

            <section id="sv2">
                <hr style="margin: 50px;">
                <img src="../images/perduco.png">
            </section>

            <section id="mt">
                    <hr style="margin: 50px;">
                    <img src="../images/perduco-sketch.png">
            </section>

            <section id="mt2">
                    <hr style="margin: 50px;">
                    <img src="../images/figma.png">
            </section>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The one picture that always shows up is perduco.png

Comment: Check in the dev tools if it is really just an invalid path or something else

Comment: The console says 403 forbidden.  Could the image itself have an embedded security setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has never occurred before and I'm not sure why it occurred this time, but the image files in question were set to private.  I use Filezilla for uploading files.  A right-click on the server image brought up a menu where I could change the privacy settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep Your Folder look like this. and try below HTML for Image.

[image]

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
```

Comment: Because one image shows up, it confirms that the file structure is set up properly.

Comment: @AvalynnCirce So, It looks like permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

"../images/imagename.jpg" will look for it in your root folder (or one folder up from "/images").
I always use "./images/imagename.jpg" and it always works.

Your browser might be caching images incorrectly. Try opening developer tools (if using chrome) choosing the network tab and disabling cache when dev tools are open.

Otherwise, check your console in dev tools for possible errors as to why they aren't showing.

Comment: I tried this fix and get the same result.  1 image shows up and 4 do not.